# Movie about a young boy with an alien father coming to find him

Tags: story-identification

I saw this movie on the Syfy channel years ago at night.

- The film was a mix of a horror/science-fiction where a little boy's father was an alien who was coming to find him and killed anyone in his way.
- The boy had problems too because the town knew he was different and feared him.
- A woman came to the town and was his helper along the way.

Comment: Colour/bw? American/British/other?

Comment: Syfy channel? Are you sure it wasn't pro-wrestling?

Comment: It was american in color. It looked like an early to mode 2000s film or somewhere made in the 90s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "[The Day the World Ended](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0272575/)", a 2002 made-for-TV movie.

[This review](http://www.themoviescene.co.uk/reviews/the-day-the-world-ended/the-day-the-world-ended.html) describes the film;

> Dr. Jennifer Stillman (Nastassja Kinski) arrives in the small
>   community of Sierra Vista where she is to take a position as the
>   school district doctor. But as she drives through the small town she
>   is stared at and stopped by the local Sheriff who doesn't make her
>   overly welcome. And so it goes on as the locals are not keen on having
>   an outsider in their midst especially when she starts talking to young
>   Ben McCann (Bobby Edner) who everyone seems not only protective of but
>   scared of as well. As Jennifer tries to get to the bottom of things
>   she discovers that something happened to his mum when he was very
>   young and he now believes his father is an alien who will be returning
>   for him.

Comment: That's the movie. Thank you

Comment: @cameron - Would you like to press the "yeah" button for me...http://www.myinstants.com/instant/yeah/

Comment: @cameron - And don't forget to mark as "accepted".